# AngularJS - calling a function onload

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a silly issue when trying to simply call a function... basically what I'm trying to achieve is to load it when i click a button, and it's proving mighty difficult:

This is my function, simple as pie:

```
window.introRegistration = function(){
  introJs().start();
}
```

in app.coffee:

```
$rootScope.introStart = ->
  alert 'works' #(alert works)
  window.introRegistration()
```

and in my view:

```
<a class="btn blue" href="/me" ng-click="introStart()">Start</a>
```

Comment: So is something happening when you click on the button? Do you get any error in the console? Otherwise, you should probably provide more information about the structure of your application. Do you have controllers? Is the button within an ngApp directive? Finally, you shouldn't attach a function to the window object, but rather attach it to a scope (preferably local scope, or rootScope if it really has to be global).

Comment: mmh no errors, and yes something happens when i click the button... thx for the suggestions, I'll work on it a little more

Comment: I fixed it. Since my click was then loading a new view, adding a delay fixed it. Thanks a lot.